# Python server not receiving UDP packet sent by a C++ client (winsock2) on the same machine

Tags: python, c++, udp, winsock2

I've tried it with a Python client and everything works fine, but with a C++ client the packet doesn't reach the Python server.

Both the client and the server are running on the same computer. I have also disabled the Windows firewall and got the same result. The Python server is listening on port 50000. For the IP address I've tried localhost and 127.0.0.1

Python server code:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

while 1:
    data, info = s.recvfrom(4096)
    print 'got' + repr(data)
```

C++ client code:

```
#include <string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char* pkt = "Message to be sent";
    const char* host = "localhost"; // tried 127.0.0.1 here as well
    sockaddr_in dest;
    sockaddr_in local;
    WSAData data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
    char srcAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char destAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, host, srcAddr);
    local.sin_port = htons(0);

    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, host, destAddr);
    dest.sin_port = htons(50000);

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bind(s, (sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local));

    sendto(s, pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0, (sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: inet_pton will fail because srcAddr/destAddr contain garbage that isn't a valid IP address.

Comment: Are you sure? From my understanding of the documentation, srcAddr and destAddr are where the numeric binary representation of the IP address will be stored when the inet_pton function completes. Documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Create a C++ client first and check if that will accept your packets. That way you can decide where the problem is

Comment: @Chuque Oops, you're right. Still notice that the binary representation of the IP address *will be stored in `srcAddr` and `destAddr`.* It will not be stored in the return value. It will return 1 (meaning success) or 0 (meaning failure) or -1 (meaning an error occurred) and you are trying to use that as the address.

Comment: Also, localhost is not a valid IP address.

Comment: @immibis It works! By assigning s_addr to the buffers after calling inet_pton and using 127.0.01, the packet reaches destination. I really should have read the documentation better about inet_pton. Part of the confusion comes from the IDE that tells you to replace inet_addr with inet_pton when in reality it's more like: create a buffer, pass it to inet_pton, and then replace inet_addr with that buffer. Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like you found something, with help. Please create an answer post. (I am aware that this is long ago, but I am an optimist.)